# Auto Layout with UITableViewCell subclass Xib file

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview controller with default style tableview cell (id: regularCell). In the cell, I wanted to display another table view (with its own cell). I named the cell with custom content customCell). Right now my view hierarchy is tableview1->regularCell->customCell->tableview2.

When I tried to load the xib file in tableview1 cellForRowAtIndexPath, I got the error that some tableview cell constrain is set to zero and the system is ignoring it and set the height to default height.

I am confused as I set both the estimatedHeight and HeightForRowAtIndexPath to 44 (not sure where this magic number comes from).

I am also in general confused about how to set auto layout right so that the heights of cells for tableview1 and tableview2 are correctly displayed.

Comment: The contraints and the the delegate methods for the tableviews are two different things. You need to look at your cell classes and figure out the constraint issue..Are you doing this in IB or in code?

Comment: I agree that constraints and delegates are different. But I am not sure which takes precedence. Here is my understanding so far, after watching the WWDC 2012 video on auto layout. Since constraints specify the relationship between parent and children, as XIBs do not have parents in the IB at design time, one has to put in code to set the translateAutoResizeIntoConstraints to NO, and code the constraints between XIB and its parent view (in my case, pin the customCell to the regularCell). This is why I set the delegate height methods. How do I set the relative heights between the two cells?